# Improperly formatted output on badges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, character-escaping

On the [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) page, there is erroneous output:

[image: badge issue]

The single quote in that word is being double escaped.

Comment: Who keeps messing with all the escaping on the site??

Comment: Same thing appears in chrome

Comment: -1, needs hand-drawn red circle. (ok, +1 for real...)

Comment: @Wooble Good idea, thanks.

Comment: More importantly… why isn’t everyone just using a proper ’‽

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is ’‽

Comment: @SteveP. the `'` is a common-or-garden apostrophe (minitech was complaining about the source using `&rsquo;` instead of `&apos;`); the other thing is an [interrobang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang).

Comment: @michaelb958 Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.

Consequence of moving that text into an actual `System.String` in the Razor view, where for whatever reason we had the entity instead of `'` (which Razor would have encoded) in the original literal write.

Answer (score 3):

It'll happen in any browser. Looking at the source

```
<p>
   Silver badges are less common than bronze ones. You&amp;rsquo;ll need to plan your strategy to get one of these.
</p>
```

`&amp;` should have been `&`.

Comment: FWIW, I checked the other `&amp;` on the page and they are okay. It's just this odd one.

Comment: I made [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16626) as your last suggested edit for any post in Meta.SO. http://i.stack.imgur.com/QsKk3.png :)